# Combine C and TCL using Swig

Tags: c, tcl, swig, dlsym

I have been following a tutorial to combine C with TCL using Swig. The tutorial seemed to be properly working but at the end I ran into an error that I cannot solve. The situation is as follows:

The tutorial I was following is:
http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html.

I have a file named test.c:

```
char *HelloWorld()
{
    return "hello world";
}
```

and another named test.i:

```
%module test
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
extern char *HelloWorld();
%}

extern char *HelloWorld();
```

I then used the following command line arguments to ready the correct files:

```
gcc -c test.c -o test.o
swig -tcl test.i 
gcc -c test_wrap.c -o test_wrap.o
gcc -dynamiclib -framework Tcl  test.o test_wrap.o -o test.so
```

And finally I tried to load it using:

```
tclsh
% load test.so test
```

This is the point where I received the following error:

```
dlsym(0x100600090, Test_Unload): symbol not founddlsym(0x100600090, Test_SafeUnload): symbol not found
```

As far as I know I did not stray from the tutorial. Can anyone tell me how it is that I got this error and more importantly how to get rid of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tcl has its own *excellent* interface to C code. I would recommend to just study it instead of wasting time on SWIG.

Comment: I would but the reason I'm doing this tutorial is so I can later use an already provided SWIG interface and C file in my TCL scripts. I'm afraid it wont work with other ways of using C code in TCL.

Comment: do a 'file test.so' and  'nm -AC test.so' and show output

Answer (score 1):

Are those error messages stopping the `load` from working? They shouldn't; they're reporting that the low-level API for supporting unloading of the extension isn't present, but that's OK (lots of extensions can't be unloaded; it's tricky to write code that supports it).

You don't mention exactly which version of Tcl you are using — but it must be at least 8.5 for those symbols to be even searched for in the first place — so it is a little hard to guess what the exact underlying issue is. (The message should simply not be reported.) I advise filing a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=add&group_id=10894&atid=110894) on this; *make sure you include all* exact *versions in your report.*

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since I used SWIG, so I'm not sure whether it gives you sufficient control over the code it generates for you to be able to apply this fix. Glossing over that detail, I can reproduce (and fix) the issue with the following:

In 'ext.c':

```
#include <tcl.h>

int DLLEXPORT Ext_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp) {


    if (Tcl_InitStubs(interp, TCL_VERSION, 0) == NULL) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }
    if (Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "Ext", "0.0") == TCL_ERROR) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Build, run tclsh, load extension:

```
$ gcc -dynamiclib -framework Tcl ext.c -o ext.so
$ tclsh8.5
% load ./ext.so
dlsym(0x400000, Ext_SafeInit): symbol not found
dlsym(0x400000, Ext_Unload): symbol not found
dlsym(0x400000, Ext_SafeUnload): symbol not found
```

Something internal to the library loading code is putting that error message into the interpreters result. To stop the message ever surfacing, set or reset the result so that the _Init() function ends with one or other of:

```
//    Set the result to a message of your choosing
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewStringObj("ok", -1));

//    Or clear out the result altogether
    Tcl_ResetResult(interp);
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

The [init block](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn44) feature of swig *might* insert code in the right place to achieve the same thing:

```
%init %{
Tcl_ResetResult(interp);
%}
```